# PHP Post script not working

Tags: php, yql, yahoo-finance

So I am trying to make a simple webpage that takes a users name and desired ticker on one page and fetch data on the second page as part of a school project. For some reason, the POST method is not working when I am trying to pass data. Any help with this would be great. Thanks!

**form.php**

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="getdata.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name">
Ticker: <input type="text" name="ticker">
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**getdata.html**

```
<html>
 <body>

 Hello <?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>!<br>
 Your ticker is 

<?php 

echo $_POST["ticker"]; 

$endpoint = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql";

$ticker = "'".$_POST["ticker"]."'";
$query = urlencode("env 'store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys';select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in (".$ticker.")");
$ch = curl_init($endpoint.'?q='.$query. '&format=json');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_error($ch)){
    die(curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);

echo'<pre>';

$result = json_decode($result);


$symbol =  $result->query->results->quote->symbol;
print_r($symbol);






?>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: change getdata.html to getdata.php

Comment: 'Is not working' - succinct, accurate and totally useless as a diagnostic aid. Describe what should happen and what is actually happening. Include any error messages - and make sure you've checked your server error logs.

Comment: is it getdata.html ? because your form's action is getdata.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getdata.html` file must be a **php** file. Rename it to `getdata.php`

Answer (score 1):

You are calling a PHP page in action, but you action page "getdata" not php, try it after rename it getdata.html to getdata.php

Answer (score 1):

You should change the extension of file `getdata` to get the data `ticker` from `form.php`.

Use,

```
getdata.php
```

Instead of

```
getdata.html
```

Answer (score 1):

first change getdata.html to getdata.php and in your php code is better use isset() function

be successfull

Answer (score 0):

Change `getdata.html` to `getdata.php` (Also in the `<form>` tag).